# Creating Gridview column Header by loading data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to bind my grid column header names by retrieving data from a table. This table has two fields, DomainID and DomainName, I want to display the DomainNames as Column header of the Grid. 
Actually I am creating employee grid view. I want all the domain names of employee to be displayed as a header and i have to check the corresponding domain in Checkbox.

Please Give me some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to show in the Grid. Where to show the Employee-Name and the CheckBoxes?

Comment: Employee Name and ID fields are coming in first, then the dynamic headings have to come at the end Edit and Delete., checkboxes will come in rows, it will be checked for the corresponding domains.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understood....

1. Make a grid view
2. Create two columns: 
     a. TextBoxColumn
     b. CheckBoxColumn
3. Set your column header using .HeaderText property
4. Add the columns to your data grid view
5. Query your database and get the data_table from it
6. using dgv.DataSource = data_table bind your data to the table
   OR
   Make a for loop for all rows in the data_table and add each row explicitly
7. For getting your checkboxes to work, handle the cellContentClick event of the data grid view and perform the necessary updates in your database.....

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 1):

You could load the headers into a `DataTable` and then create them dynamically with a custom `TemplateField`.

Here's the aspx part:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" runat="server" >
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Aqua" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee" SortExpression="Employee">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenEmpID" Value='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:label runat="server" ID="LblEmployee" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeName") %>'></asp:label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="BtnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" onclick="BtnSave_Click" />
```

Here's a complete sample:

```
public partial class GridTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateGridColumns();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) BindGrid();
    }

    private void CreateGridColumns()
    {
        var tblDomain = GetDomains();
        // Create dynamic TemplateFields
        foreach (DataRow row in tblDomain.Rows)
        {
            String domainName = row.Field<String>("DomainName");
            TemplateField field = new TemplateField();
            //Initalize the DataField value.
            field.ItemTemplate = new GridViewCheckBoxTemplate(ListItemType.Item, domaninName);
            field.HeaderText = domainName;
            //Add the newly created field to the GridView.
            GridView1.Columns.Add(field);
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetDomains()
    {
        var tblDomain = new DataTable();
        tblDomain.Columns.Add("DomainID", typeof(int));
        tblDomain.Columns.Add("DomainName");
        tblDomain.Rows.Add(1, "Google.com");
        tblDomain.Rows.Add(2, "Yahoo.com");
        tblDomain.Rows.Add(3, "Msn.com");
        tblDomain.Rows.Add(4, "Youtube.com");
        tblDomain.Rows.Add(5, "Myspace.com");
        tblDomain.Rows.Add(6, "Facebook.com");
        tblDomain.Rows.Add(7, "Wikipedia.org");
        return tblDomain;
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        var tblDomain = GetDomains(); // load domains from database or wherever
        var tblData = new DataTable();// load sample data
        tblData.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", typeof(int));
        tblData.Columns.Add("EmployeeName");
        //add domains as DataTable-Columns 
        foreach (DataRow row in tblDomain.Rows)
        {
            String domaninName = row.Field<String>("DomainName");
            //Add column from domain-name
            tblData.Columns.Add(domaninName, typeof(bool)); //CheckBox-Checked is a boolean
        }

        //get some Employees and random checked state
        var rnd = new Random();
        var empRow = tblData.NewRow();
        empRow["EmployeeID"] = 1;
        empRow["EmployeeName"] = "Jon";
        foreach (DataRow dom in tblDomain.Rows)
        {
            empRow[dom.Field<String>("DomainName")] = rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0;
        }
        tblData.Rows.Add(empRow);
        empRow = tblData.NewRow();
        empRow["EmployeeID"] = 2;
        empRow["EmployeeName"] = "Eric";
        foreach (DataRow dom in tblDomain.Rows)
        {
            empRow[dom.Field<String>("DomainName")] = rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0;
        }
        tblData.Rows.Add(empRow);
        empRow = tblData.NewRow();
        empRow["EmployeeID"] = 3;
        empRow["EmployeeName"] = "Alain";
        foreach (DataRow dom in tblDomain.Rows)
        {
            empRow[dom.Field<String>("DomainName")] = rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0;
        }
        tblData.Rows.Add(empRow);

        GridView1.DataSource = tblData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    // show how to retrieve all checkbox values and the according EmployeeID
    protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 0) return;
        var checkBoxColumns = GridView1.Columns.Cast<DataControlField>()
            .Select((bf,index) => new{Field=bf, Index=index})
            .Where(f => f.Field.GetType() == typeof(TemplateField) && ((TemplateField)f.Field).ItemTemplate.GetType() == typeof(GridViewCheckBoxTemplate))
            .ToArray();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int EmployeeID = int.Parse(((HiddenField)row.FindControl("HiddenEmpID")).Value);
            foreach (var f in checkBoxColumns)
            {
                String domain = f.Field.HeaderText;
                bool isChecked = row.Controls[f.Index].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().First().Checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the custom `ITemplate`:

```
public class GridViewCheckBoxTemplate : ITemplate
{
    ListItemType _templateType;
    string _columnName;

    public GridViewCheckBoxTemplate(ListItemType type, string colname)
    {
        _templateType = type;
        _columnName = colname;
    }

    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        switch (_templateType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Header:
               break;
            case ListItemType.Item:
                var chb1 = new CheckBox();
                chb1.DataBinding += new EventHandler(CB_DataBinding);
                container.Controls.Add(chb1);
                break;
            case ListItemType.EditItem:
                //As, I am not using any EditItem, I didnot added any code here.
                break;
            case ListItemType.Footer:
                break;
        }
    }

    void CB_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)chb.NamingContainer;
        object dataValue = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[_columnName];
        chb.Checked = dataValue != DBNull.Value && (bool)dataValue;
    }
}
```