# Error while Dynamically creating Checkbox Header template in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I used @Tim Schmelter code ([Creating Gridview column Header by loading data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119060/creating-gridview-column-header-by-loading-data-from-database)) for ItemTemplate Checkboxes its working fine but when use HeaderTemplate, I'm getting an error at ITemplate --> CB_DataBinding --> object dataValue = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)[_columnName]; saying NullReference since DataItem is Null. MyCode:

```
private void CreateGridColumns()
        {
            var tblAllowanceGroup = GetAllowanceGroup();
            foreach (DataRow row in tblAllowanceGroup.Rows)
            { ...
              field.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewCheckBoxTemplate(ListItemType.Header, AllowanceGroupName);
              gvEmpSalaryStructure.Columns.Add(field);
            }
private void BindGrid()
        {
            var tblAllowanceGroup = GetAllowanceGroup();
            DataSet dsgrid = new DataSet();
            DataTable dtgrid = new DataTable();
            var empRow = dtgrid.NewRow();
            dtgrid.Columns.Add("EmpName");


foreach (DataRow row in tblAllowanceGroup.Rows)
            {
                String AllowanceGroupName = row.Field<String>("AllowanceName");
                //Add column from domain-name
                dtgrid.Columns.Add(AllowanceGroupName, typeof(bool)); 

//CheckBox-Checked is a boolean
    //This gives me only Header Text of Gridview
                    }
```

I Want GridView dynamically generated Headers which should contain Checkboxes. And want changes should I Make ITemplate CB_DataBinding to work with ListItemType.Header.

And When we check the checkbox in the Header column all the checkboxes in that column should be checked.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OnRowDataBound` event of the gridview to loop the header row and insert a CheckBox in each Cell.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                checkBox.CssClass = "headerCheckBox";
                checkBox.ID = "headerCheckBox_" + i;
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(checkBox);
            }
        }
    }
```

And now you can bind a jQuery listener to the CheckBox class to handle the checking/unchecking of the entire column.